# Why does joining on different data types produce a conversion type inconsistently?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

As I try to join tables together on a value that's represented in different data types, I get really odd errors. Please consider the following:

I have two tables; let's say one is in database "CoffeeWarehouse," and the other is in database "CoffeeAnalytics":

Table 1: `CoffeeWarehouse.dbo.BeanInfo`

Table 2: `CoffeeAnalytics.dbo.BeanOrderRecord`

Now, both tables have a field called `OrderNumber` (although in table 2, it's spelled as`[order number]`); in Table 1, it's represented as a `string`, and in Table 2, it's represented as a `float`.

I proceed to join the tables together:

```
SELECT ordernumber,
   bor.*
FROM CoffeeWarehouse.dbo.BeanInfo AS bni
     LEFT JOIN CoffeeAnalytics.dbo.BeanOrderRecord AS bor ON bor.[order number] = bni.ordernumber;
```

If I specify the order numbers I'd like by adding the following:

`WHERE bni.ordernumber = '48911'`

then I see the complete table I'd like- all the fields from the table I've joined are populated properly.

If I add more order numbers, it works too:

`WHERE bni.ordernumber IN ('48911', '83716', '98811', ...)`

**Now for the problem:**

Suppose I want to select everything in the table where another field, i.e. `CountryOfOrigin`, is not null. I'm not going to enter several thousand order numbers- I just want to use a `where` clause to weed out the rows with incomplete data.

So I add the following to my original query:

`WHERE bor.CountryOfOrigin IS NOT NULL`

When I execute, I get this error:

`Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to float.`

I get the same error if I even simply use this as a where clause:

`WHERE bni.ordernumber IS NOT NULL`

Why is this the case? When I specify the ordernumber, the join works well- when I want to select many ordernumbers, I get a conversion error.

Any help/insight?

Comment: I couldn't read past your OrderNumber being float. Why would that ever be the case?

Comment: @samyi The quick answer is "corporate bureaucracy." I would have stored it as a string.

Comment: Try `SELECT MAX(CAST(OrderNumber AS FLOAT)) FROM BeanInfo` and you may find that you have strings that just don't convert to floats.  Or perhaps `SELECT TOP(1000) OrderNumber FROM BeanInfo ORDER BY OrderNumber DESC` or `SELECT * FROM BeanInfo WHERE IsNumeric(OrderNumber) = 0` to see if there are any in there?  Then, either correct those values, or revert to ***explicit*** casting...  `ON CAST(bor.[order number] AS NVARCHAR(32)) = bni.ordernumber`

Comment: As for ***why?*** Give two ***complete*** queries, one which works and one which errors.  Then we'll compare them for you.  But it will come down to Data Type Order Of Precedence and the operations you're applying to those fields.

Comment: There must be a value in VARCHAR version of OrderNumber that is not convertible to FLOAT. Try explicitly converting float to varchar before doing the join. Either CTE, temp table, or subquery. Or all of the above.

Comment: An Integer would be like... a million times better choice then a float. Who the hell would choose a float? AHHH!

Comment: @JNevil - They're great for nested sets...  Can't think or anything else I've used them to be an identifier...

Comment: @MatBailie I don't know anything about Nested Sets (I looked it up and decided to continue to be ignorant of them), so I'll have to take your word for it. It's frightening to think that an order number might be subject to some oddball esoteric floating point rounding error. We have a warehouse stock discrepancy on line 2.000000000000567 of order 10156.999999865132. Please inform the customer.

Comment: @JNevill nested sets are an alternative to adjacency lists for hierarchies. They are wicked fast once you understand them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model But a float for that type of implementation is still entirely the wrong choice. A numeric would be FAR superior because you don't get rounding errors. And I couldn't possibly agree more at how just dreadful a float is for an OrderNumber. Or how dreadful the OP's desire to use varchar is.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for that link. I do recall bumping into these in the past, it may have been you that threw them at me a year or so ago. I should probably invest some time on the subject so my brain doesn't scramble when I ask the obvious "How much work is it to add a new element to the hierarchy?" ahhhh! I'm sure there is some algorithm to make it snappy.

Comment: What indexes involving the order number, if any, are defined on the tables?

Answer (score 3):

The SQL Server query optimiser can choose different paths to get your results, even with the same query from minute to minute.

In this query, say:

```
SELECT ordernumber,
   bor.*
FROM CoffeeWarehouse.dbo.BeanInfo AS bni
     LEFT JOIN CoffeeAnalytics.dbo.BeanOrderRecord AS bor ON bor.[order number] = bni.ordernumber
WHERE bni.ordernumber = '48911';
```

The query optimiser may, for example, take one of two paths:

- It may choose to use `BeanInfo` as the "driving" table, use an index to narrow down the rows in that table to, say, a single row with order number 48911, and *then* join to `BeanOrderRecord` using just that one order number.
- It may choose to use `BeanOrderRecord` as the driving table, join the two tables together by order number to get a full set of results, and *then* filter that resultset by the order number.

Which path the query optimiser takes will depend on a variety of things, including defined indexes, the number of rows in the table, cardinality, and so on.

Now, if it just so happens that one of your order numbers *isn't convertible to a float*—say someone typed '!2345' by accident—the first optimiser choice may always work, and the second one may always fail. But you don't get to choose which path the optimiser takes.

This is why you're seeing what you think of as weird results. In one of your queries, all the order numbers are being analysed and that's triggering the error, in another only order numbers that are convertible to float are being analysed, so there's no error. But it's basically just luck that it's working out the way it is. It could just as well be the other way around, or neither query might ever work.

This is one reason it's bad to store things in inappropriate data types. Fixing that would be the obvious solution.

A dirty and terrible fix, however, might be to always cast your `FLOAT` to a `VARCHAR` when doing the order number comparison, as I believe it's always safe to cast from `FLOAT` to `VARCHAR`. Though you may need to experiment to make sure the resulting `VARCHAR` value is formatted the same as your order number (or cast to `INTEGER` first...)

You'll have to resort to some quite fiddly trickery to get any performance out of your existing setup, though. If they were both `VARCHAR` values you could easily make the table join very fast by indexing each order number column, but as it is the casting you'll have to do will render normal indexes unusable for a join.

If you're using a recent version of SQL Server, you can use `TRY_CAST` to find the problem row(s):

```
SELECT * FROM BeanOrderRecord WHERE TRY_CAST([order number] AS VARCHAR) IS NULL
```

...will find rows with any `FLOAT` `[order number]` which can't be converted to a `VARCAHR`.